# Percentage Vs Prior Month Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find the month on month percentage difference in excel.

Now I know how to find % Increase. `=(Increase-Previous Month)/Increase`

In the below report, I keep having to change formula's for new line.

if I have info in both month I use `=IF(AC4=0,"-",AD4/AC4-1)`

If I have only figures in the new month I use `=IF(AC15=0,IF(AD15<>0,"100%","-"),AC15/AD15-1)`

What Formula must i use if I only got figures in Sep but not (Error)

[image]

is there a way I can only use 1 formula for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula for all rows:

```
IF(OR(AC3=0),IF(OR(AD3=0),0,1),AD3/AC3-1)
```

The result will look like this:

[image: Result of the formula]